# C++ Winsock Sending Vectors Possible?

Tags: c++

I am making a client and server program that sends files back and forth. I am able to send files with a normal char array but when I try to send a file with a char vector the client doesn't even receive the vector. Im wondering if its possible to even send vectors through sockets?

Here is what I have so far:

```
std::ifstream fl("C:\\fsd.txt");
    std::cout << "1\n\n";
    fl.seekg(0, fl.end);
    std::cout << "2\n\n";
    int length = fl.tellg();
    std::cout << "3\n\n";
    std::vector<unsigned char> bufferSize(length, 0);
    std::cout << "4\n\n";
    fl.seekg(0, fl.beg);
    std::cout << "5\n\n";
    fl.read((char*)&bufferSize[0], length);
    std::cout << "6\n\n";

    std::cout << bufferSize[0] << std::endl;
    send(newConnection, (char*)&bufferSize[0], sizeof(bufferSize), 0);
```

Here is the Clients version:

```
 std::cout << "Connected to server.\n" << std::endl;

    std::vector<unsigned char> fileSize;
    std::cout << "Test1" << std::endl;
    if (recv(Connection, (char*)&fileSize[0], sizeof(fileSize), 0) < 0)
    {
        std::cout << "Test2" << std::endl;
        std::cout << fileSize.size() << std::endl;
        puts("Recv failed\n");
        system("pause");
        return -1;
    }
    else
    {
// recieve data and send back ack and the get file size
        std::cout << "Test3" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "File recieved: " << std::endl;
        std::cout << fileSize[0] << std::endl;

        const char *path = "C:/Users/Public/fsd.txt";
        std::ofstream fout(path, std::ios::binary | std::ios::out);
        fout.flush();
        std::cout << &fileSize[0] << std::endl;
        fout.write((const char*)(&fileSize[0]), sizeof(fileSize));
        fout.close();

        std::cout << sizeof(fileSize) << std::endl;
        closesocket(Connection);
    }
```

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: `sizeof(bufferSize)` and `sizeof(fileSize)` doesn't do what you think it does.To get the current size of a `std::vector` use the `size()` function.

Comment: Calling a vector `bufferSize ` is just confusing you, and us. But basically, no, you cannot send structures containing pointers over a socket with a simple send().

Comment: @Neil Sending the contents of a `std::vector<unsigned char>`over the wire will work just fine.

Comment: @πάντα  Sending a representation of the contents, yes, sending the vector, no.